# How to query a ormlite database on windows

Tags: windows, sqlite, ormlite

I forgot how to query a ormlite database on my windows system. I already solved it but cannot remember.

I have android app with a ormlite database, Now I downloaded the database file from the device and want to query this, so that i can check whats in it. I think I used a firefox plugin?? Maybe someone can help me with this

thanks

Comment: I found it

https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Answer (score -1):

You can use [SQLiteDatabseBrowser](https://www.google.com/url?sa=f&rct=j&url=http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/&q=&esrc=s&ei=h_XLUbOfH8eWtAbfxoGwCQ&usg=AFQjCNE2CI6Hh7L1IXR3SexI-qabxz_wrA).